# Solving a differential equation using Euler's method: my answer does not match key

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Here is the problem:

> Assume that the deer population of a park is governed by the
>   differential equation $$\frac{dy}{dt} = 0.2y(e^{1-\frac y5}-1)$$ where
>   y is in hundreds of deers and t is in years. Using Euler's method with
>   20 steps, estimate the population 20 years later if the initial
>   population is 150.

Here is my solution:

We have the initial value problem, $\frac{dy}{dt} = 0.2y(e^{1-\frac y5}-1), y(0) = 150$. To use Euler's method with $n = 20$, we set $\Delta t = 1$ so that we have $t_1 = 1, t_2 = 2, \dots, t_{20} = 20$. We compute y successively using $y_n = y_{n-1} + f(t_{n-1}, y_{n-1})\Delta t$, where $f(t, y) = \frac{dy}{dt}$. We get the following values:

```
t   y
0   150
1   120
2   96.0000000025
3   76.8000002414
4   61.440009104
5   49.1521611569
6   39.3231662824
7   31.4667442165
8   25.2050188497
9   20.2526350059
10  16.3938355394
11  13.4508482494
12  11.2569832176
13  9.6497222556
14  8.4812868483
15  7.6305244207
16  7.0061981559
17  6.5430739006
18  6.1955891025
19  5.9320561442
20  5.7302858354
```

So my answer is 573. But the key is 491. Where was I wrong?

Comment: Evidently, you've used the wrong starting value. Should be 1.5 instead of 150...

Comment: @ParclyTaxel Thank you. I get the right answer now.